# Proving a condition for when 2 bases are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm currently attempting a problem in a linear algebra textbook. In the solution sheet this statement is said to be a necessary and sufficient condition for the union of 2 bases to be a basis but i have no clue how to prove it.

$$B_1 \cup B_2 \text{ is linearly independent} \iff span(B_1 \cap B_2) = span(B_1) \cap span(B_2)$$
Where $B_1$ and $B_2$ are bases

I think maybe in the $\Longrightarrow $ direction the union of $B_1$ and $B_2$ being linearly independent implies $span(B_1) \cap span(B_2) \subseteq span(B_1 \cap B_2)$ ? but i'm not sure where to go from here.
I don't know where to start in the $\Longleftarrow$ direction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $sp(B_1)=W_1,sp(B_2)=W_2$(sp stands for span)

$B_1 \cup B_2$ spans $W_1+W_2$. Let $w \in W_1+W_2$. Then we have $w=w_1+w_2, w_1 \in W_1, w_2 \in W_2$ by definition. $w_1$ is a linear combination of the vectors in $B_1$. Similarly $w_2$ is a linear combination of vectors in $B_2$. So, we have $w$ is a linear combination of $B_1 \cup B_2$.

$B_1 \cap B_2$ is linearly independent in $W_1 \cap W_2$(straightforward from the condition that the vectors in a basis are linearly independent).

Now,

$$B_1 \cup B_2 \text{ is linearly independant} \iff B_1 \cup B_2$$ form a basis of $W_1+W_2$
$$\iff \dim(W_1+W_2)=|B_1 \cup B_2|=\dim(W_1)+\dim(W_2)-\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$$(well known result)
$$\iff |B_1 \cup B_2| = |B_1| + |B_2| - \dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$$
$$\iff \dim(W_1 \cap W_2) = |B_1 \cap B_2|$$
$$\iff B_1 \cap B_2$$ form a basis of $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$
$$\iff sp(B_1 \cap B_2) = W_1 \cap W_2 = sp(B_1) \cap sp(B_2)$$